# How to use order by clause for dates

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, date

How would you go about getting the most recent date from a table?
I've been trying to use the clause order by but I get back the following error: "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

```
FROM Account_Salesforce B   
Inner JOIN Contact_Salesforce A   
ON A.AccountId = B.Id
Left Join  Movimento__c_Salesforce C
on C.Cliente__c = B.Id
WHERE   B.KPIUltimoSoggiornoAnno__c >= 2021 
ORDER BY C.Data_Inserimento__c desc
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This appears to be generic SQL, not Salesforce SOQL, so would likely be more on topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps it's for marketing-cloud (and is missing a tag)?

Comment: @DavidReed it's  Sql and thats why it's probably not working on Marketing Cloud. I opened the question due to I'd like to know the correct sintax on SOQL.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easiest just to use `top 100 percent` like this:

```sql
select top 100 percent 
b.id
FROM Account_Salesforce B   
Inner JOIN Contact_Salesforce A ON A.AccountId = B.Id
Left Join  Movimento__c_Salesforce C on C.Cliente__c = B.Id
WHERE B.KPIUltimoSoggiornoAnno__c >= 2021 
ORDER BY C.Data_Inserimento__c desc
```

Note that `top` doesn't work in Query Studio, but it does in a Query Activity.